# MySQL last record in each group with multiple records in same date

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the sample data

```
row_id  cust txn_dt       txn_amount
-------------------------------------
1       1    31-01-2018   3000
2       1    04-02-2018   4000
3       1    04-02-2018   6000
4       2    29-01-2018   2500
5       2    02-02-2018   3900
6       1    01-02-2018   5000
7       1    01-02-2018   3900
```

Below is the Expected output

```
row_id  cust txn_dt       txn_amount
-------------------------------------
3       1    04-02-2018   6000
5       2    02-02-2018   3900
```

Need to pick the latest record for each customer based on date and then row_id

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried

Comment: Store dates as dates (if you're not doing so already)

Comment: its being stored as string and changing the column type would be a huge impact

Comment: is `row_id` also being stored as a string?

Comment: No its integer.

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky when there are two columns that define the ordering.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.row_id = (select t2.row_id
                  from t t2
                  where t2.cust = t.cust
                  order by t2.txn_date desc, row_id desc
                  limit 1
                 );
```

An index on `t(cust, txn_date, row_id)` should help performance a bit.

Comment: Forgot `limit 1`?

Comment: <code>select t.*
from customer_accounting t
where t.row_id = (select t2.row_id
                  from customer_accounting t2
                  where t2.customer_id = t.customer_id
                  order by str_to_date(t2.txn_dt, '%d-%m-%Y') desc, t2.row_id desc
                 );<code>
This just returns OK and no results

Comment: After adding the LIMIT 1 its giving the result but takes 16 secs which is huge for 300 customers

Comment: the  ordering by `txn_date` isn't going to sort in "date" value order, if the column is varchar with values stored in format `'DD-MM-YYYY'`

Comment: i have used str_to_date(t2.txn_dt, '%d-%m-%Y')

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that will return the specified result:

```
SELECT t.row_id
     , t.cust
     , t.txn_date
     , t.txn_amount
  FROM ( SELECT r.cust
              , MAX(r.row_id) AS max_row_id
           FROM ( SELECT p.cust
                       , DATE_FORMAT(
                           MAX( 
                             STR_TO_DATE( p.txn_date ,'%d-%m-%Y')
                           )
                         ,'%d-%m-%Y'
                         ) AS max_txn_date 
                    FROM sample_data p
                   GROUP BY p.cust
                ) q
           JOIN sample_data r
             ON r.cust     = q.cust
            AND r.txn_date = q.max_txn_date
          GROUP BY r.cust
       ) s
  JOIN sample_data t
    ON t.cust   = s.cust
   AND t.row_id = s.max_row_id
 ORDER BY t.row_id ASC
```

Inline view `q` gets the latest `txn_date` for each `cust`

inline view `s` gets the maximum `row_id` value for the latest `txn_date` for each `cust`

(If `txn_date` column was `DATE` datatype, we could avoid the rigmarole of the `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE_FORMAT` functions. And with an appropriate index available, we would (likely) avoid a full scan and an expensive "Using filesort" operation.)

Comment: This gave me the correct output with least query execution time of just 1.6 secs